# How exactly did Din Djarin fall?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the end of season 3 episode 2 of the Mandalorian,
<sub>Heavily spoilered since its a new episode</sub>

> when he's at the living waters of mandalore, in the mines, he apparently drops into the water. When Bo Katan goes to save him, she has to go some distance to find... he's apparently just taking a nap underwater. There's no tentacle monster or other threat and Bo just underwater jet packs him out. Did he just take a bad step, and... roll the whole way down?

Comment: I mean, he's dressed head-to-toe in metal armour. I'm not sure if beskar has some magical low-density properties, but this could just be him stepping off an underwater cliff and sinking like an ingot.

Comment: Which is plausible due to the blood loss. But he seems to have fallen a looooong way

Comment: Sure, but what else could he do? You ever tried to swim with twenty kilos of metal strapped to your back?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the third episode has revealed: -

> It didn't used to have such an immediate drop-off. The bombings caused seismic shifts that apparently collapsed the lake bed, opening up into a chamber underneath.

So he fell because 1) he took a step expecting there to be floor where there wasn't any, and 2) he's wearing a heavy metal suit. Those tend not to be terribly buoyant.

Comment: He also explicitly says " I saw the chasm passing me as I fell. I didn't realise it was so deep". Interestingly in a previous episode, when he fell in the water, he used his jetpack to come up, and he'd taken off his jetpack.

Answer (score 7):

> There's no tentacle monster or other threat

Incorrect.

> There was (what is strongly implied to be) a mythosaur, the ancient creature subdued and tamed by Mandalore the Great, as recalled by Bo-Katan just a few minutes prior. As she ascends with Din, her torch shines on the creature's face and eye:
>
>  [image]

The obvious implication is that

> the mythosaur seized Din's leg and dragged him underwater, though why it simply left him at the bottom without killing or eating him is as yet unclear.

I doubt that Din simply fell, because

> Bo-Katan took only a few seconds to leap in after him and had her jetpack on the whole way down, and still only caught up to him after he'd already hit the bottom, which suggests that something actively dragged him down at high speed. If he'd simply fallen, then even with his armour on, the water resistance should have slowed him enough for Bo-Katan to catch up with him easily.

Comment: I'm vaguely doubtful since the <redacted> seemed... chill. It really looked like he fell down.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I agree that <redacted> seemed peaceful, and it's definitely odd, but Din simply falling seems impossible to me given how quickly he reached the bottom. I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: Also what did it grab him *with*?